# I want to send email from the site to a mailling list

Tags: email

My site is an administrative site and used by a small number of inside staff.  We have multiple maillist and at times need to send an email to the list.  I want to use a communicate type form from the site not CP so that my users just have one place to go for everything.  I have tried tell_a_friend but cannot get it to work.

Comment: I think, it wouldn't be possible without any third-party addon (if any) or you will need to develop an addon for it.